# Play a YouTube video in Lightbox in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

In my WordPress plugin I need a LightBox style popup to open and play a YouTube video. The plugin has a custom post type, users have already provided a YouTube URL which is saved as post_meta.

I've got a thumbnail of the video and thought I would be able to create a popup link with the oembed function but obviously that did not help. Not sure what the best way to proceed is from here.

EDIT: Code request by comment

```
            // Get the URL of the video
            $wdm_youtube = get_post_meta($wdm_auction->ID, 'wdm_youtube', true);
            if ($wdm_youtube != '') {
                // Get the video ID
                preg_match('#(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&?\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^"&?\n]+|(?<=‌​‌​(?:v|i)=)[^&?\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&?\n]+#', $wdm_youtube, $matches);
                if (!empty($matches)) {
                    // This gives an iframe link
                    $link = wp_oembed_get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $matches[0]);

                    // main-img-a is for a local old lightbox lib that came with a plugin, no docs or link known
                    // All this code does is opens a larger image in a lightbox, no video
                    echo '<a class="main-img-a" href="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/' . $matches[0] . '/sddefault.jpg">';
                    echo '<img id="wdm_youtube_image" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/' . $matches[0] . '/hqdefault.jpg" />';
                    echo '</a>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried to achieve this ?

Comment: I've updated but I feel it hinders rather than helps. I'm not able to get the oembed code to work with the LightBox lib installed and would prefer advice on where to get and how to use a newer LightBox lib.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with [BOOTSTRAP modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and iframe. But this below code on your plugin file.

```
<div id="VideoModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg video-modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <iframe src="" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add this jquery function in your Plugin's script file

```
$('.showVideoModal').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var video_id = $(this).data("vimeo-id");
var video_width = $(this).data("vimeo-width");
var video_height = $(this).data("vimeo-height");


  $('#VideoModal').modal({show:true}); 

    $('#VideoModal iframe').attr("width",video_width);
    $('#VideoModal iframe').attr("height",video_height);
    var frameSrc = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/"+ video_id+"?autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0";
    $('#VideoModal iframe').attr("src",frameSrc);
  });
  $('#VideoModal .close').on('click',function(){
    $('#VideoModal iframe').attr('src','');
  });
```

Now the popup and popup trigger is ready. Let get the post thumbnail and make it as popup trigger point by below code. Include this lines in your same plugin file.

```
<pre>
    <a href="#" class="showVideoModal"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
</pre>
```

Hope this will help.